Is `int x;` really just a declaration or an implicit definition too?
In C, suppose an object is declared, for instance int x; as an automatic variable. Without initializing it with any value, is it still considered just a declaration and not definition?
Cause ChatGPT argues that when an object is declared, sometimes the compiler sets aside some memory associated with it (object). Therefore it is an implied definition. Please only answer if you are completely sure with the C semantics.

int x; is a definition, not a declaration.

@NullUserException what would you call int x; int x; which is perfectly valid? (outside of a function). Also this int xx; int xx = 1; is valid. Which is the declaration and which is the definition?

@WeatherVane Very interesting. I always assumed the compiler would throw an error at those (like it would if they were done inside a function).

The question doesn't really make sense because a definition (whether tentative or not) is also a declaration. It should ask "Is int x; really just a declaration or an implicit definition?".

See also What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?  The question is tagged with both C and C++; you have to scroll past a few C++ answers to find the C answers.

@WeatherVane I knew I wasn't crazy! I spun up a DOS emulator and tried to compile a program with MS C 1.04 (from 1983), and if you add int x; int x; (outside of a function) the compiler will choke with Error 63: duplicate declaration of item "x". This wasn't always legal

@NullUserException with MSVC now, it's the initialised int x = 1; int x = 1; that causes a compiler error.

An object declared at file scope without an initializer as in this case is considered a tentative definition.  Other identical declarations may appear, each of which is also a tentative definition.
If no definition (i.e. one with an initializer) exists, then that tentative definition, along with any others that may appear, are considered a "full" definition for that identifier which is initialized to 0.
This is spelled out in section 6.9.2p2 of the C standard:

A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope
without an initializer, and without a storage-class specifier or with
the storage-class specifier static, constitutes a tentative
definition. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative
definitions for an identifier, and the translation unit contains no
external definition for that identifier, then the behavior is exactly
as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that
identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation
unit, with an initializer equal to 0.

Such a declaration at block scope (i.e. in the body of a function) is a unique declaration for that object and is also a definition, as such a declaration sets aside storage for that object.
All definitions are also declarations, as stated in section 6.7p5:

A declaration specifies the interpretation and attributes of a set of
identifiers. A definition of an identifier is a declaration for
that identifier that:

for an object, causes storage to be reserved for that object;
for a function, includes the function body;
for an enumeration constant, is the (only) declaration of the identifier;
for a typedef name, is the first (or only) declaration of the identifier.



Got my vote, but a word on if x is an automatic variable may be useful too.

If an object is declared without any explicit initialization, it would be a tentative definition. When declared at a global scope, it would be automatically allocated a value of 0. Turning it into a full-definition?

@Bobby Without initializer; At file scope: A tentative definition, initialized to 0 (unless a definition with an initializer also appears at file scope example). Inside a function: A definition of an automatic variable (with an indeterminate value).

@Bobby More than one tentative definition of an object can appear, and all would refer to the same object.

@Bobby As many tentative definitions as you like and at most one full definition. It will only be initialized to 0 if there is no full definition at the end of the compilation unit. (Typically, implementations will place tentatively defined variables in a BSS section, or possibly in a COMMON section, depending on the compiler options.)


Declaration:
A declaration introduces the name of a variable, function, or type to the compiler. It specifies the type of the entity but does not allocate memory (for variables) or provide implementation (for functions).
Key Characteristics:

Informs the compiler about the name and type of the entity.
Does not allocate memory for variables or define the body of functions.


Definition:
A definition not only declares the entity but also allocates memory (for variables) or provides the implementation (for functions).
Key Characteristics:

A definition is a declaration plus additional information (memory allocation or implementation).
There can only be one definition of a variable or function in a program (except the possibility of having Tentative Definitions of the same object in many compilation units).






Aspect
Declaration
Definition
Tentative Definition




Purpose
Introduces an entity to the compiler.
Allocates memory (for variables) or provides implementation (for functions).
Serves as a placeholder; acts as a definition if no full definition is provided later.


Memory Allocation
No (for variables).
Yes (for variables).
Allocates memory only if no other definition exists in the same translation unit.


Function Body
No (only function prototype).
Yes (full implementation).
Not applicable (only for objects, not functions).


Multiplicity
Can appear multiple times in a program.
Must appear exactly once for each entity.
Can appear multiple times; merged into one definition.


Storage Duration
N/A (does not allocate memory).
Allocates memory for static duration objects.
Allocates memory for static duration objects if no full definition is present.


Initialization
Not applicable.
Variables can be initialized (e.g., int x = 5;).
Initialized to zero if no full definition is provided.


Examples (Variables)
extern int x;
int x = 42;
int x;


Examples (Functions)
int add(int a, int b);
int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
Not applicable (only applies to variables).



So int x; is a declaration and definition (tentative definition in the file scope) in both file and block scope.
Declarations and definitions are mentioned in the C standard in many places:

6.2.2: Linkages of Identifiers
6.7: Declarations
6.7.6: Declarators
6.9: External Definitions
6.9.1: Function Definitions
6.9.2: External Object Definitions


Can I know the reason for DV?

Strictly, C only allows one definition of a variable in multiple translation units. However, C compilers with a Unix pedigree often allow an extension described in Annex J.5.11 of the C standard. It's a 'common' extension — a double entendre because it was commonly found in compilers and because it emulated Fortran's COMMON blocks.  GCC 10 and above now follow the standard more strictly by default by using -fno-common; the old behaviour defaulted to using -fcommon.  See also How do I use extern to share variables between source files?

@JonathanLeffler I was writing about tentative definitions

Re “There can only be one definition of a variable or function in a program (except the possibility of having Tentative Definitions of the same object in many compilation units)”: The C standard makes no distinction between multiple definitions from tentative definitions and multiple definitions from regular definitions.

@JonathanLeffler: Re “Strictly, C only allows”: Strictly, the C standard allows multiple external definitions. Programs with multiple external definitions are conforming to the standard, in the absence of any other issue. The standard does not define their behavior.
